# Is it possible to integrate Square with an e-commerce web site?

Tags: java, php, objective-c, e-commerce, mobile-website

A client has a [Square](https://squareup.com/help/en-us) configuration which handles payments. They will try to set up an e-commerce web site (probably in PHP). Now, they want to make paying available through mobile also.

I was thinking that a mobile e-commerce web site could be set up with jquery Mobile for example, but when I saw that [currently Square doesn't offer an API](https://squareup.com/help/en-us/article/3853-square-api.html), I gave up the idea that e-commerce web site could integrate with Square. **Have someone done this? Is integrating Sqaure with a mobile/web app of any kind (not just PHP) possible?**

I was looking at their (Square's) native [mobile wallet (stored credit) solution](https://squareup.com/help/en-us/article/3910-square-wallet-overview). But, the clients needs a bit more customization. Customers would want to make payments on their way to the physical shop/store and would like to get feedback which would be generated using the data available in the square system (for example using [analytics from here](https://squareup.com/help/en-us/article/5072-summaries-and-reports-with-square-register)). **Have someone done this till now? Is this possible?**

Comment: Apple does not own Square. Square is its own company.

Comment: my bad. :( any answer to the question though?

Comment: Please vote this question for reopening. The below statement of not being constructive isn't giving any explanation. What is not constructive? The question is clear "Has someone integrated Square with any app?". There is no discussion yet being done to label it as not constructive. And I already found an answer http://www.payitsquare.com/api (they have offered an API couple of days ago).